# Node.js: Getting EC2 instances information by using describeLoadBalancers

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to get metadata of AWS cloud inventory. That includes Load balancers, Number of EC2 instances per load balancer, State and config of those instances, other configuration etc.

Currently I am using `describeLoadBalancers` and then when I get description I just parse instances information out of it.

Here is script (after loading the AWS SDK and setting apt region. Credentials are stored in file)

```
var elb = new AWS.ELB();
// var elb = new AWS.ELBv2({apiVersion: '2015-12-01'}); // For this, inside function ProcessDescriptions I get error: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

elb.describeLoadBalancers(null, ProcessDescriptions);

function ProcessDescriptions(err, descriptions)
{
    if (err != undefined)
    {
        console.log (JSON.stringify(err));
    }
    else
    {
        descriptions.LoadBalancerDescriptions.forEach(ProcessDescription);
        // console.log (JSON.stringify(descriptions));
    }
}

function ProcessDescription(description)
{
    if(description.Instances[0] != undefined)
    {
        console.log(description.Instances[0].InstanceId);
        console.log(description.LoadBalancerName);
    }
}
```

**Problems:**

1. With `AWS.ELB` script runs but doesn't return all load balancers.
2. With `AWS.ELBv2` script runs and returns missing load balancer in #1 (in `descriptions`). But unfortunately I get error `Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined`. Basically I don't get `LoadBalancerDescriptions` in JSON response causing the error.

**Questions:**

I need to know is this appropriate way to get load balancers and EC2 inventory? What is difference between `AWS.ELB` and `AWS.ELBv2`? How can I get all load balancers along with info of EC2 instances attached to them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between AWS.ELB and AWS.ELBv2 is that they interface with the different versions of load balancer in AWS. AWS.ELBv2 will work with newer generations of load balancers (Application load balancers and Network load balancers). AWS.ELB will only work with load balancers that are of type Classic

With ALB and NLB you have the concept of [Target Groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-target-groups.html), which are what you register instances against. You need to query the target groups for the instance information.

You'll have to forgive the quick and rough code, but it demonstrates the steps needed to get the instances registered to the ALBs/NLBs from the target groups.

You'll probably need to modify this code to suit your needs.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({region: 'eu-west-2'});

// create the promise object for ELB call
var elb_describe = new AWS.ELB().describeLoadBalancers().promise();

// handle the promise object
elb_describe.then(
  function(data) {
    for (i = 0; i < (data.LoadBalancerDescriptions).length; i++) {
        console.log(`Instances attached to ${data.LoadBalancerDescriptions[i].LoadBalancerName}`)
        for (j = 0;  j < (data.LoadBalancerDescriptions[0].Instances).length; j++) {
            console.log(data.LoadBalancerDescriptions[0].Instances[j])
        } 
    }
  },
  function(error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
);

// create promise object for elbv2 call
var elbv2_describe = new AWS.ELBv2().describeLoadBalancers().promise();

// handle the promise object
elbv2_describe.then(
  function(data) {
   // for number of results returned in describe load balancers call
   for (i = 0; i < (data.LoadBalancers).length; i++) {
        let lb_arn = data.LoadBalancers[i].LoadBalancerArn
        // get Target groups associated with the load balancer 
        elbv2_get_target_groups = new AWS.ELBv2().describeTargetGroups({ LoadBalancerArn: lb_arn}).promise();
        elbv2_get_target_groups.then(
            function(data) {
                //only selecting the first result from the results, will need modifying for LBs forwarding to multiple TGs
                let tg_arn = data.TargetGroups[0].TargetGroupArn
                // get target health of instances registered to the target group (only way I could find of getting the instance-id)
                elbv2_get_target_health = new AWS.ELBv2().describeTargetHealth({ TargetGroupArn: tg_arn}).promise();
                elbv2_get_target_health.then(
                    function(data) {
                        console.log(`Instances registered to '${tg_arn}', associated with ${lb_arn}`)
                        for (j = 0; j < (data.TargetHealthDescriptions).length; j++) {
                            console.log(data.TargetHealthDescriptions[j].Target)
                        }
                    }
                )
            }
        )
    }
  },
  function(error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
);
```